# Unflatten Dictionary Structure to Nested Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to unflatten a list of dictionary items to a nested dictionary structure which should contain the following structure

```
Bus
   Message
          Fieldname
```

I currently have a way to get the messages inside the bus but this will only result in a single message being added to each bus because I end up overwriting the dictionary within the bus with the new message. Actual output below

```
{'BUS_A': {'MSG_1': None}, 'BUS_B': {'MSG_2': None}}
```

How can I create the below desired input from the input data including the bus items, messages and fields?

A complete, executable example of where I've currently got to so far.

```
signals = [{"bus":"BUS_A", "message":"MSG_1", "fieldname":"Signal1"},
           {"bus":"BUS_A", "message":"MSG_2", "fieldname":"Signal2"},
           {"bus":"BUS_B", "message":"MSG_3", "fieldname":"Signal3"},
           {"bus":"BUS_B", "message":"MSG_4", "fieldname":"Signal4"}]

desired_output = {"BUS_A":
                      {"MSG_1":
                           {"Signal1":None},
                       "MSG_2":
                            {"Signal2":None},
                       },
                  "BUS_B":
                      {"MSG_3":
                           {"Signal3":None},
                       "MSG_4":
                            {"Signal4":None},
                       }
                  }



def Unflatten(signals):
    buses = {item['bus']:{} for item in signals}
    for bus in buses:
        for item in signals:
            if item['bus'] == bus:
                buses[bus] = {item['message']:None}
    print(buses)

Unflatten(signals)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `defaultdict` saves you a lot of hassle having to conditionally set up the structure of the dictionary:

```
>>> signals = [{"bus":"BUS_A", "message":"MSG_1", "fieldname":"Signal1"},
...            {"bus":"BUS_A", "message":"MSG_1", "fieldname":"Signal2"},
...            {"bus":"BUS_B", "message":"MSG_2", "fieldname":"Signal3"},
...            {"bus":"BUS_B", "message":"MSG_2", "fieldname":"Signal4"}]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> buses = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
>>> for s in signals:
...     buses[s["bus"]][s["message"]][s["fieldname"]] = None
...
>>> buses
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x00000265E25451F0>, {'BUS_A': defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'MSG_1': {'Signal1': None, 'Signal2': None}}), 'BUS_B': defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'MSG_2': {'Signal3': None, 'Signal4': None}})})
```

Without `defaultdict` you need to initialize each value to an empty dictionary as needed:

```
>>> buses = {}
>>> buses = {}
>>> for s in signals:
...     if s["bus"] not in buses:
...         buses[s["bus"]] = {}
...     if s["message"] not in buses[s["bus"]]:
...         buses[s["bus"]][s["message"]] = {}
...     buses[s["bus"]][s["message"]][s["fieldname"]] = None
...
>>> buses
{'BUS_A': {'MSG_1': {'Signal1': None, 'Signal2': None}}, 'BUS_B': {'MSG_2': {'Signal3': None, 'Signal4': None}}}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had tried defaultdict but couldn't get the syntax correct for the dictionary below the top level.

Comment: Checked this out, Not sure the defaultdict method works but the non-defaultdict method works as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach. It slims down some of the property juggling by starting with an object that already has 2 empty busses. This method is probably inferior to `defaultdict`, but it illustrates the logic behind unflattening your signals more directly. I can't pretend to know what you are doing, but this all seems like a bad way to do it, and to some degree pointless. What is the real outcome of this method ~ you assigned `None` to a signal name. All the data is already there, changing it's form is probably entirely unnecessary. Your 2 Busses should probably just be separate instantiations of a `Bus` class which has methods that can parse and organize the data that is fed to it. If you use a `dataclass` you could also use `asdict` (when/if necessary) to pass it's properties to whatever is expecting the data as a `dict`.

```
def unflatten(signals) -> dict:
    busses = {'BUS_A':dict(), 'BUS_B':dict()}
    for obj in signals:
        bus, msg, sig = obj['bus'], obj['message'], obj['fieldname']
        
        if not msg in busses[bus]:
            busses[bus][msg] = dict()
        
        busses[bus][msg][sig] = None
            
    return busses
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll check this out. The data comes from a JSON file but needs to be converted to a nested XML so I'm going through a nested dictionary before using element tree to create the XML

Comment: @scotty3785 - I see. Maybe the way you are doing it is valid, after all.